# Reducing a Matlab table with

Tags: matlab, merge, parallel-processing, reduce

What is the fastest way to reduce a MATLAB table with multiple rows per timestamp to a table with only one row per timestamp and at the same time merging the other values into this one row ?  (See: Example of before and after)

As I have to handle large amounts of data is there a way of doing this in parallel (parfor, ...) ?

**BEFORE:**

```
Timestamp  Value01   Value02   Value03
_________  _______   _______   _______

1001       01        02        []          
1001       []        []        []          
1001       []        []        03          
1002       []        []        07          
1002       []        09        []          
1003       04        01        []
1003       []        []        []         
1004       05        06        08
```

**AFTER:**

```
Timestamp  Value01   Value02   Value03
_________  _______   _______   _______

1001       01        02        03          
1002       []        09        07          
1003       04        01        []         
1004       05        06        08
```

Comment: You didn't say how this table is stored - as a matrix or as a cell?

Comment: @smlq There's this thing called a `table` in MATLAB (since 2014b or so), I guess he uses that. Matrix is impossible, since that does not support the empty element assignment `[]`

Comment: Yes, I'm using the matlab table format.

Comment: Probably the best would be to have an example that embed the code for the creation of such a table

Comment: Please change your `table` examples to actual MATLAB code that we can just paste into MATLAB to get an example of your datastructure. Also, what happens if one of the Value columns has multiple values for a single timestamp?

Comment: You can `stack()` and `unstack()` the table to get what you want, as long as row/colum values are non overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question interesting and tried to find solution. Now want to show you my approach.

First of all I tried to use `union` function but it works a bit confusing for me with `tables` so only way I found - is to convert table to `cell` and `numeric` data, work with it and then create new table.

Here the  code:

```
tab = table2cell(MyTable(:,2:end))                  % convert to cell
tab( cellfun('isempty',tab) ) = {[0]}               % replace [] with [0]
tab = cell2mat(tab)                                 % convert to numeric
t = MyTable(:,{'Timestamp'})                        % lets take a time
t = table2array(t)                                  % to numeric too
t = t - 1000
fun = @(x) sum( tab( find (t == x),:),1)            % find the sum of rows with the same time
arr = [1:t(end)]'   %'                              % how many sums we need
carr = arrayfun(fun, arr, 'uniformoutput',false)    
result = cell2mat(carr)
```

And the result is:

```
 result =

 1     2     3
 0     9     7
 4     1     0
 5     6     8
```

The last step - create new table. It's just the example:

```
Value01 = result(:,1)
Value01 = num2cell(Value01)
Value01(find([Value01{:}]==0)) = {[]}
%... the same for Value02 and Value03
NewTable = table(1000+arr,Value01, Value02, Value03, 'VariableNames',{'Timestamp', 'v1','v2','v3'})


NewTable = 

Timestamp    v1     v2     v3 
_________    ___    ___    ___

1001         [1]    [2]    [3]
1002         []     [9]    [7]
1003         [4]    [1]    [] 
1004         [5]    [6]    [8]
```

Already I finished this answer I thought about your data... Looks like it's `strings` - because you have `01` not `1`... But I still think my solution is right just need  to rewrite a bit if you really have a `strings` :)